# mysql_num_rows() returns 1 every other time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

The following block of code is ran in a loop, and creates/modifies data for child rows when a report is saved:

```
function save_report_module2_importers($data)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_rep_mod2_importers', array('report_id' => $data['page_data1']['report_id'], 'id' => $data['id'], 'company_id' => $data['page_data1']['company_id']));

    if($query->num_rows() == 0 || !isset($data['id']))
    {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_rep_mod2_importers', $data['page_data1']);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('report_id', $data['page_data1']['report_id']);
        $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->update('tbl_rep_mod2_importers', $data['page_data1']);
        $res = $query->row();
        return $res->id;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In the case of a new child row, the passed `$data['id']` (PK) value is of course null. The query is supposed to return 0 rows of course. It works as expected on my dev box, as well as my remote staging server, running WAMP and LAMP stacks respectively.

The issue is on the company's production server, wherein upon inserting a new report with new child rows, every other instance of `num_rows()` returns 1 instead of always 0. There should be no rows with a null PK though. Doing a raw `mysql_num_rows()` or `mysqli_num_rows()` exhibits the same behavior.

I noticed this behavior does not occur if I comment out the INSERT query. Basically, the next SELECT always returns 1. I've tried doubling the SELECT query, and the second one always returns 0 as expected. I figure it may be a server setting somewhere I am missing, since it works perfectly on other environments.

Have been struggling with this "issue" for days. Hope anyone can enlighten me on what the problem may be. Thanks!

Comment: Symptoms like an _every other_ pattern can be indicative of issues in an entirely different area, such as the code being _called twice_.  Have a look in the server access logs -  is something like an HTTPS redirect causing the code to be called twice? Is an empty `src=` attribute in an `<img>` or `<script>` tag or empty `href` in a `<link>` tag present? That would make 2 requests for the same URI.

Comment: Depending on how URL rewriting is structured, weird things can even happen if favicon.ico is not present.

Comment: Regardless of how many times the code is called though, num_rows() should never be returning anything other than 0 in this instance since a null id is passed.

Comment: Have you debugged to verify that `$data['id']` is truly `NULL` as opposed to zero or an empty string, for example? Those would pass `isset()`.

Comment: Yes I have, and it is indeed null each time. Also tried last_query() and the query is exactly the same for each iteration, yet gives alternating results.

Comment: Like I said though, it only occurs on one environment. The code works as expected elsewhere.